# Fix LVM physical volume definition after removing /dev/sdb

Tags: partition, lvm

Recently I set up LVM partition with an new disc /dev/sdc.
I created the LVM with the following commands:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdc
vgcreate data /dev/sdc
mkfs.ext4 /dev/data/srv
tune2fs -m 0 /dev/mapper/data-srv
```

Now the problem is that the old disc /dev/sdb is gone  and I get errors in /var/log/messages like:

```
sd 2:0:2:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
sd 2:0:2:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 3f 00 00 04 00
blk_update_request: 8 callbacks suppressed
end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 63
sd 2:0:2:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
sd 2:0:2:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
sd 2:0:2:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 3f 00 00 04 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 63
sd 2:0:2:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
```

Because the old disc /dev/sdb was removed after crating the LVM, /dev/sdc (which is no longer present) took its place:

```
>pvs
  /dev/sdc1: read failed after 0 of 2048 at 0: Input/output error
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sdb   data lvm2 a--  330.00g    0

>lvscan
  /dev/sdc1: read failed after 0 of 2048 at 0: Input/output error
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/srv' [330.00 GiB] inherit
```

The partition works fine though /sdc is no longer present. 
Nevertheless how can I  fix the LVM to no longer search for /dev/sdc?

I think LVM uses UUIDs internally. Otherwise this scenario wouldn't recognize sdb as the correct pv (disc) .

Comment: If `sdc` was still in use (active lv, no reboot), it should not have turned into `sdb`. Unless you disconnected and reconnected it also, creating a frankensdc in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't restart the host I fixed the error:

```
>pvs
  /dev/sdc1: read failed after 0 of 2048 at 0: Input/output error
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sdb   data lvm2 a--  330.00g    0
```

by typing:

> echo 1 > /sys/block/sdc/device/delete